# evaluate the line integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the line integral $\int_{C}^{ }xe^{y}ds$, where $C$ is the line segment from $(-1,2)$ to $(1,1)$.

I know that I need to first get a parametrized equation. I got $r(t) = [(2t - 1), (-t + 1)]$. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Well replace $C$ by $[0,1]$, $x$ and $y$ by their expression in terms of $t$ and $ds$ by $dt$. By the way, $ds$ sounds like a surface, which it is not.

Comment: Make sure you got the right parametrization.

Answer (score 0):

So, we have $x(t)=2t-1$ and $y(t)=2-t$ (going from $(-1,2)$ to $(1,1)$).

Then use partial integration for
$$\int_0^1(2t-1)\,e^{2-t}\cdot\sqrt5\,dt$$
where $\sqrt5$ is the (length) of the differencial of $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, you need the following identity

> $$ \int_{C}^{ }xe^{y}ds = \int_{a}^{b }x(t)e^{y(t)}\sqrt{ \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2 }dt. $$

**Note:**

$$ s(t)=\int_{0}^{t}|r'(\tau)| d\tau .$$