# Evaluation of a line integral

Tags: calculus

Calculate $\int_Γ f dl =$ for:

$f(x,y) =(x+y)e^y$, $(0,0)   -> (2,4)$

so part of the answer is:

$Γ(t) = (2t,4t)$  ,$t$ is in $[0,1]$

$\int_0^{1} ((2t+4t)e^{4t} (2^2+4^2)^{1/2})dt =...$

but I didnt understand why is there $ (2^2+4^2)^{1/2}$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\int_Γ f dl$?

Comment: So, what is the definition, and what do you get when you apply it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_\Gamma f d\ell=\int_0^1 f(\Gamma(t))\|\dot\Gamma(t)\|dt$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441689/evaluate-the-line-integral)

> $$ dl = \sqrt{ \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2 } $$